# Use require on import * as in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have the following import:

```js
import * as firebaseui from "firebaseui";
```

How should I use it with `require`, because when I use the following code:

```js
const firebaseui = require("firebaseui");
```

The object `firebaseui` returns `undefined`; meaning the import was not successful.

Comment: Why do you want to use CJS instead of ESM? You can't use `require` with an ES module but I don't know if you can use `require` with `firebaseui` (i.e. if `firebaseui` is an ES module).

Comment: const { firebaseui } = require("firebaseui"); ?

Comment: @S.Ramjit I don't know if it works. I haven't tried it but it would be pretty strange (at least for me). The equivalent to `const { firebaseui } = require("firebaseui");` is `import { firebaseui } from "firebaseui";`. That's different to `import * as firebaseui from "firebaseui";`.

Comment: the syntax looks correct.  I would check as others mention, about running ES/CJS mix...for example does your JSON config have module set?  does firebaseui support ES or CJS?